# Why does my intent shut off the application?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

This intent at the bottom of the page simply says that it is unable to start the event. I have tried to use this intent to start every other activity, and it just doesn't work whereas the intent to start anything in my main activity work just fine... anyway any feedback is appreciated.

```
package com.chich;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class second_activity extends Activity
{
@Override
public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) 
{
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.main2 );  
    getWindow().setWindowAnimations( 0 );


    Toast toast=Toast.makeText(this, "Your incoming texts and calls are now being   blocked.", 2000);
     toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, -30, 50);
     toast.show();


    ImageView Image2 = ( ImageView ) findViewById( R.id.Image2 );
    Image2.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick( View Image2 ) 
        {    

            Intent intent = new Intent(second_activity.this,   third_activity.class);            
            startActivity(intent);
        }    

    });
}

}
```

Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.chich"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS">
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS">
</uses-permission>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".chich_activity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".second_activity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
              <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
              </activity>
              <activity android:name=".third_activity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
              <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
              </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver"> 
        <intent-filter android:priority="9999999" >
            <action android:name = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /> 
        </intent-filter> 
    </receiver>
</application>
</manifest>
```

I'm not sure what it means but here's my LogCat info: 02-08 03:11:00.062: D/UnlockClock(2500): GMT_update mRightNow.getTimeZone().getID() == America/Los_Angeles 02-08 03:11:00.077: D/UnlockClock(2500): GMT_update current == America/Los_Angeles, TimeZone.getTimeZone(current).getID() == America/Los_Angeles 02-08 03:11:05.319: D/dalvikvm(17812): GC_EXPLICIT freed 6871 objects / 411088 bytes in 151ms 02-08 03:11:07.058: I/3gw.Service(3071): Mobile Network connected - not roaming 02-08 03:11:07.527: D/dalvikvm(2500): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 39720 objects / 2083360 bytes in 94ms 02-08 03:11:14.194: D/dalvikvm(16583): GC_EXPLICIT freed 413 objects / 21640 bytes in 138ms 02-08 03:11:19.179: D/dalvikvm(18220): GC_EXPLICIT freed 168 objects / 9000 bytes in 124ms 02-08 03:11:27.089: D/dalvikvm(17515): GC_EXPLICIT freed 3 objects / 72 bytes in 221ms 02-08 03:11:32.269: D/dalvikvm(2664): GC_EXPLICIT freed 579 objects / 35824 bytes in 239ms 02-08 03:11:39.866: D/dalvikvm(16088): GC_EXPLICIT freed 854 objects / 26864 bytes in 186ms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, and the solution was actually not in code given on this page.

```
ComponentName locationReceiver = new ComponentName( second_activity.this, SmsReceiver.class );
            PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
            pm.setComponentEnabledSetting( locationReceiver,     PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP );
```

the package manager is set by default to kill the app after it has been run. You must command it not to with "PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP" at the end. What was screwy though is that it only sometimes killed the app, making it difficult to actually figure out what was wrong. Thank you all for your input, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Update your code like this
You don't need to write intent filter for each activity. just edit your Androidmanifest.xml like below `

```
 Image2.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onClick( View v) 
    {    

        Intent intent = new Intent(second_activity.this,third_activity.class);            
        startActivity(intent);
    }    

});
```

Androidmanifest.xml

```
<application
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<activity
    android:name=".chich_activity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".second_activity" ></activity>
<activity android:name=".third_activity"></activity>

</application>`
```

Comment: I just commented out the enable and disable receiver function in the third_activity, and this intent worked just fine. What about this makes the intent fail?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know only your main activity should define the intent-filters like that.  For the 2nd and third activities you only need to define the android:name.

Comment: what do you mean exactly? that we can't use intent in other activities?

Comment: right I actually changed that to the way it is in desperate hopes that it would solve the problem, but it didn't...

Comment: Hmm, you're right, what error are you actually getting? Any stack traces in LogCat?

Comment: I just commented out the enable and disable receiver function in the third_activity, and this intent worked just fine. What about this makes the intent fail?

Answer (score 0):

Re-add your activites with the xml editor in eclipse. i think you are copy&pasting your activity stuff from the main activity. simple activites (i presume second_activity and third_activity are simple activites) are not have usually launcher. and the names are without the dot. i think you already changed that.

btw: are you using eclipse? ctrl+shift+f is your friend. it applies the standard format to your text (code), making it easier to read by the people, who are accustomed to the standart java "look".

Comment: Ya tried that and they are.. but thank you for the ctrl+shift+f tool.. I didn't even know that existed.

Comment: can you debug your code to check if Image2.setOnClickListener - onClick is ever called? It looks like your manifest is ok, since you don't get any exceptions...

Comment: I would do that, but I already checked by putting a method that enables my broadcast listener (which aborts broadcasts) in the onClick, and it worked. unfortunatly it still closed the application though.

Comment: I just commented out the enable and disable receiver function in the third_activity, and this intent worked just fine. What about this makes the intent fail?